# аналогия fscanf в C++ и Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

В ходе решения задачи чтения большого файла, возникла необходимость переписывания кода с Matlab на C++.

В ходе работы возник вопрос интерпретации функции fscanf (поток, шаблон, матрица данных) в аналоги с++. В с++ имеется алогичная функция fscanf(поток, шаблон, набор переменных для выходных данных). Как видим, если в Matlab под шаблон подходит 120 строк, то он все подходящие данные шлёт в матрицу или массив, а в с++ мы должны всё разбрасывать по переменным.

Вопрос, есть ли возможность аналогичного использования fscanf в с++,как в matlab и писать данные в матрицу или другое хранилище.

Буду признателен за идеи с вашей стороны.

Comment: `fscanf` это С скорее а не С++. Массивы в С/С++ заполняется поэлементно в цикле. Возможно используя `eof` и прочие признаки конца файла.

Comment: `while (cin >> a[N]) N++` что-то такое может вам подойдёт.

Comment: Используйте input stream и переопределите оператор >> для классам матрицы.

Comment: @VTT, вы всегда выручаете меня) Уже второй раз. Можете немного пояснить, если есть время.

Comment: [input matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D++input+matrix)